# React VS angular: Real-time application with large data to show in datagrids in real-time

Tags: angular, reactjs, web-applications

I am deciding which JavaScript framework to learn and use for my new web application. The application is real-time in nature and must be a web application. By real-time, it means that it will have to show lots of texture data in data grids very fast. My application is similar to application [openmct](https://github.com/nasa/openmct) by NASA.

**Can anyone please come up with some comparisons?**

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons of both js.

The Bi-Directional Data Binding is the feature that sets Angular and React only implement one-way binding of data.

And as per [Description of openmct](https://github.com/nasa/openmct), it is working with bi-directional data binding. So therefore you can use angular.

But you also mentioned that you have to work with large database then you can go with **React**. The reason behind this is Virtual Dom.

React involves different approaches to lower the amount of DOM operation, betters and hastens the update process.**Virtual DOM is also of use as developers manage the large database.**

For more info,visit this [Link](https://appinventiv.com/blog/react-vs-angular).